# Export from Query to Excel, while defining Row to export to

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have seen a bunch of ways to export data into excel worksheets form queries, yet I cannot find one that I can define the starting row I would like the insertion of the query data to begin.

For example, I would like the first 5 columns of my query to go into columns A8-F8, and the rest of the columns from my query to go into columns H8-Y8.

Is there a way to specify where my data from the query should start pasting, and the starting row as well?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a null value for the 6th position of your query.

Comment: Sure, but I still need the insertion begin at row 8, and not 1.

Comment: Can't find anything on that.  If you can get 7 empty rows at the beginning of your query results, then that would do it for you.  Adding an UNION clause with blank results might be the direction to go.

Comment: Right, but in those first seven rows of my excel sheet, I have data I don't want to be overwritten by blank data, hence I need the insert to start at row 8.